# How to change role of user in Asp.net Membership using SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I have two roles in my web-application. Now I want to change the roles of some users. Can any one tell me How to change the User Roles using SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use defalt RoleProvider and table for user roles was created by aspnet_regsql.exe. So all you need is 
 - find specified user in table Memberships
 - find specified user role in table Roles
 - add a record to table UsersInRoles with specified membership id and specified role id

Comment: Your solution works. First I create User and then assign a User ID and Role Id in UserInRole. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the System.Web.Security there is a Role class that has a AddUsersToRole method.

Example to use:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole("userName", "roleName");
```

and there is the same to remove:

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("userName", "roleName");
```

or using sql as you asked: When you run the aspnet_regsql you get bunch of stored procedures.
Such a stored procedure is the one named aspnet_UsersInRolesInsert. It is for adding users to roles.

Comment: I have shared web hosting so not able to run aspnet_regsql command on that.